# How to find the nested Asp:GridView within the following code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the following structure in an aspx page:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlCust" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvMaster" runat="server" 
                  OnRowCreated="gvMaster_RowCreated">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlMaster" runat="server">
                        //...
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlDetails" runat="server">
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server">
                            <Columns>
                                //...
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

The panels are used for the CollapsiblePanelExtender from the Ajax Control Toolkit.

I am trying to use FindControl to find the gvDetails control in code-behind, but my latest attempt has not worked, which is in the gvMaster_RowCreated event:

```
GridView gv =  
e.Row.FindControl("pnlDetails").FindControl("gvDetails") as GridView;
```

where e is GridViewRowEventArgs

I am basically doing what was on this page, but I am not using a SqlDataSource, however, the person is basically finding the SqlDataSource via the FindControl from the e argument passed in from the RowCreated event.  Here is the link:

http://mosesofegypt.net/post/2008/02/Building-a-grouping-Grid-with-GridView-and-ASPNET-AJAX-toolkit-CollapsiblePanel.aspx

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Nested-GridView-Example-in-ASP-Net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code behind method which worked for me:

```
protected void gvMaster_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        GridView gv = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("gvDetails");
    }
}
```

Is your app throwing an exception? What is not working properly?

Comment: I tried that, like you have above, but I did it the following way which returned a null value:
GridView gv = e.Row.FindControl("gvDetails") as GridView;

Comment: I tried your snippet above and when I step through, gv is null.

Comment: I guess I'm stumped. Sorry! Only thing left I would try is using the RowDataBound event instead of RowCreated but it's probably a long shot.

Comment: Nate, Sorry, you were right.  Stupid me had the spelling of the GridView ID as gvDtails in the markup, so that is why it wasn't finding it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that a GridView can have child controls like that.

Comment: Which child controls are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the panel inside a template field. You can try something like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlCust" runat="server"> 
    <asp:GridView ID="gvMaster" runat="server" >
        <columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlDetails" runat="server">
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvDtails" runat="server">
                            <columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%-- columns here --%>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </columns>
                        </asp:GridView> <%-- end gvDetails --%>
                    </asp:Panel> <%-- end pnlDetails--%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </columns>
    </asp:GridView> <%-- end gvMaster --%>
</asp:Panel> <%-- end pnlCust --%>
```

Comment: Yes, this is actually how the code is.  I just took it out for more clarity and now I am trying to find the gvDetails GridView in Code Behind.  I will update my question with the template field.